# Passing attribute from one class object to another class object

Tags: python, class, attributes

- I have two classes with two methods each.  In the methods of the first class, they are creating an instance of the second class, then calling the methods of the second class.
- The problem is that in the second class, one method uses an attribute returned by another method in the same class.  When the first-class methods call on the second-class methods, the equivalent attribute is not passed.

*My constraints are that I cannot modify the first class nor the parameters of the second class. Here is a simplified version of the code:*

```
class One():
    def f1(self,x,y):
        self.model=(x+y)
        return self.model
    def f2(self,z):
        return self.model*z

class Two():
    def f1(self,x2,y2):
        temp=One()
        return temp.f1(x2,y2)
    def f2(self,z2):
        return temp.model*z2
    
object1=One()
object1.f1(2,3)
object1.f2(4)

object2=Two()
object2.f1(1,2)
object2.f2(9)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you expect each instance of `Two` to have an instance on `One` as attribute. Try instanciating in the constructor (`__init__`):

```
class Two():
    def __init__(self):
        self.one = One()
    def f1(self,x2,y2):
        return self.one.f1(x2,y2)
    def f2(self,z2):
        return self.one.model*z2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class One():
    def f1(self,x,y):
        self.model=(x+y)
        return self.model
    def f2(self,z):
        return self.model*z
    
temp=One()
class Two():
    global temp
    def f1(self,x2,y2):
        return temp.f1(x2,y2)
    def f2(self,z2):
        return temp.model*z2
    
object1=One()
print(object1.f1(2,3))
print(object1.f2(4))

object2=Two()
print(object2.f1(1,2))
print(object2.f2(9))
```

Create `temp` variable outside the class `Two()`. Then use the `global` keyword inside the class `Two()` to access it. Now at last print all the results.